# Редактирование таблицы в javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Есть таблица tableview, в которой 2 столбца.
Как сделать что бы пользователь мог редактировать значения конкретного столбца?
Каким образом можно реализовать это?

Comment: Например пользователь кликает на конкретную ячейку и сразу же пишет туда новое значение.

Answer (score 3):

Советую прочитать [статью](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm), в которой все прекрасно описано.

Суть такова - определяешь таблицу `TableView`,  в ней определяешь колонки `TableColumn`, у которых ты определяешь listener `setOnEditCommit`.

**P.S.** не забудь у таблицы и колонок поставить признак `editable` в `true`